# Escaping backslash in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, escaping, filepath, slash

I'm trying to write an sql function in Postgresql that will parse a file path.
I want to return just the file name.

I cannot get past getting an accurate text string in the function.

Here is the function:

```
Function:  job_page("inputText" text)
DECLARE
    $5 text;

BEGIN
    $5 = quote_literal("inputText");
    return $5;
END
```

When I run this:

```
select job_page('\\CAD_SVR\CADJOBS\7512-CEDARHURST ELEMENTARY SCHOOL\7512-20.DWG')
```

I get this result:

```
"E'\\CAD_SVRCADJOBSé2-CEDARHURST ELEMENTARY SCHOOLé2-20.DWG'"
```

Postgresql interprets the slash followed by certain characters as a special character.

How do I escape?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use escape string syntax:

```
select E'\\CAD_SVR\\CADJOBS\\7512-CEDARHURST ELEMENTARY SCHOOL\\7512-20.DWG';

\CAD_SVR\CADJOBS\7512-CEDARHURST ELEMENTARY SCHOOL\7512-20.DWG
```

This will work in any case.

Or you can `set standard_conforming_strings=on` and use:

```
select '\CAD_SVR\CADJOBS\7512-CEDARHURST/ ELEMENTARY SCHOOL\7512-20.DWG';

\CAD_SVR\CADJOBS\7512-CEDARHURST/ ELEMENTARY SCHOOL\7512-20.DWG
```

`quote_literal` function should be used only when you will be constructing a query for `exec` call in pl/pgsql function. For constructing a query in a client you should use a client's library quoting function, like `PQescapeStringConn` in libpq or `pg_escape_string` in PHP. But the best option is to use prepared statements and use a string as an argument, which eliminates all quoting and is [much safer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) too.

Comment: I *am* using quote_literal in a function. See my original post.
I tried as you suggested but still don't get the correct result.

Comment: You don't understand. You're calling this job_page() function wrongly. You need to quote it's argument before calling job_page - there's no way a function will quote it's own argument properly for itself. Paste a code, where you call this function and then we'll be able to help.

Comment: The "standard_conforming_strings" option is enabled by default since PostgreSQL 9.1 (released 2011-09-12).

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the \ with another \

i.e. \\

You can change this behavior off by setting the standard_conforming_strings option to on. By default it is off, but this default will change some time in the future.

I recommend the double backslash for the time being.

Comment: Does not work in this case.
If I try replace("inputText", '\\', '\\\\') I get the same result.
Evidently pg sees \752 as a special character. (not a backslash)