# LIKE clause with \ character in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

I have this behavior in PostgreSQL 9.3:

```
-- (1) this "doesn't" work
select 't\om' like '%t\om%'
-- result = false

-- (2) this works
select 't/om' like '%t/om%'
-- result = true
```

Why is the (1) query result false? What is the best way to get true in (1) query?

Comment: its treated as escape char, try `select 't\om' like '%t\\om%'` to escape the escape charecter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\` has no special meaning in SQL **except** inside the condition for the `LIKE` operator where it can be used to escape the wildcard characters.

But you can define a different escape character for LIKE which then makes the `\` a "normal" character:

```
select 't\om' like '%t\om%' escape '#';
```

**edit**

As Sunrelax has commented, you can also use an empty string as the "escape" sequence:

```
select 't\om' like '%t\om%' escape '';
```

Comment: If you want to compare only the two strings with no escape value: 

    select 't\om' like '%t\om%' escape '';

Answer (score 2):

`\` is an escape sequence, so you need to escape it, too:

```
select 't\om' like '%t\\om%';
```

There is also a configuration option you can set. See [Escaping backslash in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049034/escaping-backslash-in-postgresql)