# PostgreSQL INSERT syntax error command error

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.1

I don't know why error when Postgres SQL run this SQL command:

```
INSERT INTO "mb_member_points" ("code","value","acc_value","cur_value","cur_acc_value") 
VALUES ('A001132451','-Qyq2\','kL0GSG',1,1);
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "kL0GSG" at character 120

[image: table struct]

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.1.3, Sequelize 4.44.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping backslash in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049034/escaping-backslash-in-postgresql)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: Postgres 8.1 has been [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) and unmaintained for nearly a decade. You should plan an upgrade to a supported version now

Comment: What is the value of [standard_conforming_strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) in your installation? You should set it to `on`

Comment: In my postgresql.config don't have setting "standard_conforming_strings". But I don't want change Postgres setting

Comment: Can I use this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22466191/4725750

Comment: You can change it for the current connection using `set standard_conforming_strings=on;` or for the current user using `alter user <your user here> set standard_conforming_strings=on;`

Comment: Why are you using such archaic, unsupported software?

Comment: Setting `standard_conforming_strings` will not work in 8.1 as it was read only in that version. An option is to do `E'-Qyq2\'`.